# Prophet of Kruphix: Can I flash Bestow?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

If I have [Prophet of Kruphix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Prophet%20of%20Kruphix) out (which gives all my creatures flash), can I use the bestow ability of my enchantment creatures during my opponents turn? For example, can I bestow [Thassa's Emissary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373735) on one of my creatures, during my opponents turn?

Bestow text for reference:

> If you cast this card for its bestow cost, it's an Aura spell with
> enchant creature. It becomes a creature again if it's not attached to
> a creature.

Similarly, if I do not have enough devotion for [Thassa, God of the Sea](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thassa%2C%20God%20of%20the%20Sea) to be a creature, can I use flash to cast her during my opponents turn?

Thassa's devotion related text, for reference:

> As long as your devotion to blue is less than five, Thassa isn't a
> creature. (Each Blue in the mana costs of permanents you control
> counts toward your devotion to blue.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can, for both. Prophet of Kruphix allows you to cast "Creature Cards" as though they had flash. Thassa's Emissary IS a Creature Card. It's NOT a "Creature", as a "Creature" is a permanent on the battlefield, which it isn't while it's in your hand or on the stack. But it IS a "Creature Card", and that's all that matters.

See rules for Bestow, noting that Bestow ability that allows you to cast it as an Aura is a static ability of the card itself, not of a creature or aura permanent.

> 702.102. Bestow
>
> > 702.102a Bestow represents two static abilities, **one that functions while the card with bestow is on the stack** and another that functions
> >     both while it's on the stack and while it's on the battlefield.
> >     "Bestow [cost]" means "You may cast this card by paying [cost] rather
> >     than its mana cost." and "If you chose to pay this spell's bestow
> >     cost, it becomes an Aura enchantment and gains enchant creature. These
> >     effects last until one of two things happens: this spell has an
> >     illegal target as it resolves or the permanent this spell becomes,
> >     becomes unattached." Paying a card's bestow cost follows the rules for
> >     paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2e–g.

Comment: You may want to add a reference to rule 702.102 that defines the ability bestow as a static ability of a card, not a creature. Just so someone does not come through in 10 min and post an answer with that information and make yours unnecessary.